Unable to delete old company OneDrive folder
I used to work at a company that used OneDrive. I neglected to unlink the OneDrive account. Now I can't delete the folder.
I started out with:
ls -lae

...

drwx------@   2 jonathan  staff     64 May  9 17:32 OneDrive-COMPANYNAME
 0: group:everyone deny writeextattr
 1: group:everyone deny delete

I booted in startup options and ran this:
csrutil disable --with basesystem --with dtrace --with kext

Next I tried various combinations of xattr, chmod, chown and ended up with this:
ls -lae
drwxrwxrwx@   2 jonathan  staff     64 May  9 17:32 OneDrive-COMPANYNAME

I still can't delete the folder, unfortunately. I'm not sure if it still has some data in it, so maybe that could be the reason. I don't really care about the data. I just want the folder gone.
Here is what I get:
rm -rf OneDrive-COMPANYNAME/
rm: OneDrive-COMPANYNAME/: Permission denied

Here is the output for xattr:
xattr -l OneDrive-COMPANYNAME                                                                           
com.apple.file-provider-domain-id: com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac.FileProvider/OneDrive - COMPANYNAME

Any help is appreciated!

Backup up everything, then reformat the drive.

What extended attributes are attached to the directory?

I'm sure you did this, but did you run the rm command using sudo? Additionally, this post might help see first reply (not the top reply): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-delete-onedrive-working-folder-after/a21414eb-3e0d-40b4-bca7-45a95d3490a6. You might need to reinstall onedrive (but I don't think you will need to sign in to an acount) to be able to delete the symlinks/caches

@SolarMike, I had done that. Unfortunately, I need to restore from backups, which includes the OneDrive folder.

@MarcWilson I added xattr above.

@jschmidt If you remove the extended attribute, can you then remove the directory?  I have no experience with the FileProvider API, but I wonder if the OS is protecting the directory for that reason.

@jschmidt A lightbulb just went on... don't specify the trailing slash.

@MarcWilson Thanks for the help! I was using the trailing slash, but then found the ResetOneDriveApp.command file in the application bundle. That did the trick!

@AVelj had the answer. The link that he provided worked!
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-delete-onedrive-working-folder-after/a21414eb-3e0d-40b4-bca7-45a95d3490a6
The posts had this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c#:~:text=1%20Open%20a%20Run%20dialog%20by%20pressing%20Windows,on%20the%20OneDrive%20desktop%20app.%20Learn%20more%20on...support.microsoft.com
The key was using the ResetOneDriveApp.command in the OneDrive bundle!
Thank you, @AVelj!
